# How to limit the number of times ForEach runs

Tags: powershell, foreach, break

I am trying to remove Exchange contacts using a CSV file, however, I want this script to stop, or never even start, if that list exceeds 25 users.

```
$RemoveContacts = Import_CSV ".\Removed Contacts_$((Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')).csv"
$RemoveContacts | ForEach { Remove-MailContact -identity $_ -confirm:$false}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Good point, @lit - I've edited the double quotes into the question to avoid a distraction, given that the problem is incidental to the question.

Answer (score 6):

If you **don't even want to *start* processing** if array `$RemoveContacts` has more than 25 users:

```
if ($RemoveContacts.Count -gt 25) {
  Write-Error "Too many contacts: $($RemoveContacts.Count)"
  return
}
```

`Write-Error` creates a non-terminating error and `return` exits the script / function.
Note that processing will continue by default, if applicable.
To abort processing instead, use `Throw` rather than `Write-Error`.

---

If you want to **process 25 elements at most**:

`Select-Object -First <n>` allows you to stop processing after the first `<n>` objects have been received:

```
$RemoveContacts | Select-Object -First 25 | ForEach { Remove-MailContact -identity $_ -confirm:$false }
```

`Select-Object -First` is the right tool to use in a *pipeline*.

However, since you've already loaded all objects into an array in memory, you can more simply - and more efficiently - use *array slicing*:

```
$RemoveContacts[0..24] | ForEach { Remove-MailContact -identity $_ -confirm:$false }
```

`[0..24]` extracts the first 25 elements from array `$RemoveContacts`, and is safe to use even if the array contains fewer elements than that.<sup>[1]</sup>

In PSv4+ you can further speed this up by using the `.ForEach()` *method* to process each array element:

```
$RemoveContacts[0..24].ForEach({ Remove-MailContact -identity $_ -confirm:$false })
```

---

<sup>[1] Unless you have deliberately activated [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 3` or higher.</sup>